# How do you compare two strings and ignore the case in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I want to write a function like equalp, which gives #t for (equalp "Xy" "xY").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use (string-ci=? "Xy" "xY")

[Reference](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Spring-2004/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Note also that PLT has `string-locale-ci=?`, which can deal with other locales.